# Was there lead in old wood stain?

Tags: wood, safety, stain, lead

Does anyone know anything about interior blue-greenish wood stain? Presumably from 1953, when my house was built. Worried because i have a little one. Would really appreciate any insight. I have been getting conflicting results with the hardware store swabs.  The (presumably) copper in the blue stain gives a positive.

Comment: Nothing should be an issue unless the little one is gnawing on the wood like a beaver, or you are doing cutting or sanding that is producing dust.

Comment: Repost/duplicate, I think...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is likely lead in stains prior to 1980ish.    Lead is very heavy and unless you are machine sanding or cutting or eating the wood it isn't much of a worry.    It is literally the most over drawn out home "issue" I have ever seen.

You can do a quick home test on it.   They have strips that will give you indicators.

Remedying it is probably just covering it with stain and poly.   I have using poly on wood but if there is lead it is a good cover.

Comment: Little ones do/get into stuff.  My parents say I used to put nails/stuff into receptacles, but I grew out of it.